# Javascript to find check and display corresponding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to create a function that finds all checked check boxes that start with a value and display the corresponding div that is hidden below.

I have an example started here: 
`Demo`: https://jsfiddle.net/3wf34nbf/3/

In the example, if the first checkbox is checked, I want to show the response to that checkbox below. The same would happen for the second checkbox.

I was thinking I could try something like this:

```
.find("div[id^=$(this)]")
```

Then change the css to `display:block` but that wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all checked checkboxes, than iterate over them.  Then for each of them you can find the related div, and show it.

To show it, I added the class *visible*, so that if *response* class has also class *visible*, you can see it, otherwise it's not visible.

Every times you click the button, the visible class is removed from every response div, so that you hide all the divs, before show the wanted divs.

```js
function postResponse() {
  $(".response").removeClass('visible');
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Response").addClass('visible');    
  });
}
```

```css
.response:not(.visible) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="test1">Test1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1">
  <label for="test2">Test2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test2">
  <div class="responseContainer">
    <div class="response" id="test1Response">
      Response for Test1
    </div>
    <div class="response" id="test2Response">
      Response for Test2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postResponse()">
      Post Data
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense but when I tried this I wasn't able to get it working: https://jsfiddle.net/3wf34nbf/6/ 
Did I miss something?

Comment: @cgrouge if you open your console you will see an error `(index):75 Uncaught ReferenceError: postResponse is not defined(…)`. That's a problem with jsfiddle that place javascript after your html, so the postResponse can't be found, look at the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09ncoj10/)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix the response to work in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3wf34nbf/7/